# Android Couchbase error getting remote checkpoint

Tags: android, json, couchbase

I am using Couchbase for my project. Well this my first time with Couchbase Lite for Android. I am currently getting this error. But I passed the correct url for the JSON Api you can find it here

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+%3D+%22YHOO%22+and
+startDate+%3D+%222015-11-02%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222016-11-02%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F
%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```

But in the LogCat I find this JSON URL :

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+%3D+%22YHOO%22+and
+startDate+%3D+%222015-11-02%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222016-11-02%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F
%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=/_local/a26bc8baaf06fc3d4d08c9b916d2a8508152b2fa
```

This is LogCat Error I am getting.

```
11-02 18:28:58.832 29526-29670/com.android.stockhawk W/Sync:
```

`com.couchbase.lite.replicator.ReplicationInternal$11@4098198: error getting remote checkpoint
                                                                 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('/' (code 47)): maybe a (non-standard) comment? (not recognized as one since Feature 'ALLOW_COMMENTS' not enabled for parser)
                                                                  at [Source: buffer(okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource@5064f7b).inputStream(); line: 1, column: 2]
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1486)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:518)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:447)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipComment(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2902)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd2(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2781)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._skipWSOrEnd(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2737)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:652)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3600)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3545)
                                                                     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2646)
                                                                     at com.couchbase.lite.replicator.RemoteRequest.executeRequest(RemoteRequest.java:275)
                                                                     at com.couchbase.lite.replicator.RemoteRequest.execute(RemoteRequest.java:165)
                                                                     at com.couchbase.lite.replicator.RemoteRequest.run(RemoteRequest.java:105)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`

This is my code for Couchbase

```
public void storeStockHistoryData(String stock_symbol){
        try {

            manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(mContext.getApplicationContext()), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
            DatabaseOptions options = new DatabaseOptions();
            options.setCreate(true);
            database = manager.openDatabase(Constants.DATABASE_NAME, options);
            com.couchbase.lite.View viewItemsByDate = database.getView("quote");
            viewItemsByDate.setMap(new Mapper() {
                @Override
                public void map(Map<String, Object> document, Emitter emitter) {
                    Object createdAt = document.get("Symbol");
                    if (createdAt != null) {
                        emitter.emit(createdAt.toString(), null);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Fetched Data: " + createdAt.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, "1.0");

            startSync(stock_symbol);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startSync(String stockSymbol) {

        String url = Utils.getStockDataUrl(stockSymbol);
        URL syncUrl;
        try {
            syncUrl = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Replication pullReplication = database.createPullReplication(syncUrl);
        pullReplication.setContinuous(true);

        Replication pushReplication = database.createPushReplication(syncUrl);
        pushReplication.setContinuous(true);

        pullReplication.start();
        pushReplication.start();

        pullReplication.addChangeListener(this);
        pushReplication.addChangeListener(this);

    }
```

Please help me figure out what is the problem as I am also running short of time for my project submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you tries to sync against Yahoo REST API with your application. But Couchbase Lite does not support the replication against Yahoo REST API or other REST APIs. Couchbase Lite provides the replication with Couchbase Server through SyncGateway or CouchDB (including Cloudant).